# What is the definition of a heapoid?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

There is a notion of 'oidification' in category theory which characterises many object versions of mathematical objects. For example:

- magmas $\rightarrow$ magmoids
- loops $\rightarrow$ loopoids
- groups $\rightarrow$ groupoids
- rings $\rightarrow$ ringoids

And in reverse, one object magmoids are magmas and so on. This is also referred to as horizontal categorification in contrast to vertical categorification.

NLab mentions that heaps have a many object oidification: heapoids. But do not give an explicit characterisation. It's not immediately obvious to me what this is, unlike the mathematical objects mentioned above, heaps are characterised by a ternary operation.

Hence I'm just looking for pointers to a definition, preferably accessible online as I don't have access to a math library.

Comment: You missed monoids --> monoidoids :) Sorry I couldn't resist.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: I've heard there are things called andr->androids! ;-).

Comment: https://planetmath.org/heap1 --- see remark number 2

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Nice find. But I think this is an example of a concept being used in two different ways. What PlanetMath is calling a heapoid is what Nlab calls a Mal'cev Operation and its also called this by Springer's Encyclopedia of Maths. For Nlab, a heapoid should be a many object generalisation of a heap and which is what I'm interested in. But the generalisation that PlanetMath is naming by the same concept is merely a generalisation that comes about by dropping a condition. Obviously if you drop a condition then specialising the object will not reintroduce that condition. In other ...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: ... words I'm not convinced that this is what I am looking for. Still, thanks for going to the trouble of locating it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The claim that heapoids exist was added to the nLab page in [revision 3](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/revision/heap/3) by [Toby Bartels](http://tobybartels.name/), so you could ask him what he had in mind.

I can speculate that a heapoid would have

- a set of objects.
- families of morphims $f:x\to y$.
- for any $f:x\to y$, $g:z\to y$, and $h:z\to w$, a ternary composite $t(h,g,f) : x\to w$ (note the reversal of direction in $g$).
- for any $f:x\to y$ and $g:x\to z$, we have $t(g,f,f) = g$.
- for any $f:x\to y$ and $g:z\to y$, we have $t(g,g,f) = f$.
- for any $f:x\to y$, $g:z\to y$, $h:z\to w$, $k:u\to w$, and $\ell : u\to v$, we have $t(\ell,k,t(h,g,f)) = t(t(\ell,k,h),g,f)$.

Then any groupoid would become a heapoid with $t(h,g,f) = h\circ g^{-1}\circ f$, just as any group becomes a heap in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks. I can now add that to my collection of oids!